# What is area of the image of the unit disk under the mapping $(x,y)\to \left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> For $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2}$, let
>              $$T(x,y)= \Big(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2} , \frac{y-x}{\sqrt2}\Big)$$
>   If $\Bbb{D}$ is the unit disc in the plane , what is area of $T(\Bbb{D})$?

I was trying this question many ways, but I could not get. This question  is given by my teacher as a homework. I was thinking about the area of the circle, but I don't know where I have to start and I don't have any hint to solve this question.

If anybody help me I would be very thankful to him.

Comment: Here is a hint: Calculate the length of the vector $T(x,y)$ and compare it to the length of $(x,y)$.

Comment: Hint: calculate the jacobian determinant of $T$.

Comment: @Chinz Your edit does not agree with the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Determinant of the matrix of $T$ it's $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=1$,

which says that the area does not change.

Comment: what is the  area  i did't get it @ michael rozenberg

Comment: @lomber lego It was an unite disk. Thus, the area is $1$.

Comment: but my teacher said area is Pi@ michael Rozend berg

Comment: @lomber lego If this disk with base is an unit circle then indeed, it's $\pi\cdot1^2=\pi$.

Comment: thanks @ michael Rozenberg

Comment: @You are welcome! My English is very bad. I am sorry! Indeed, the area of an unit disk it's $\pi\cdot1^2=\pi$. I just did not know what is the dick! Now, I know.

Answer (score 1):

This T is rotation around (0,0) for 45 degree, thus it preserves area.

Say $z=x+yi$, then $T(z) = (\cos 45+i\sin 45)\cdot z$

Comment: but what will be area @ john nobody

Comment: $\pi r^2 .....$